# WAMP - AutobahnJS: Multiple subscriptions when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, autobahn, crossbar, wamp-protocol

I'm using Crossbar as a WAMP router and publishing events that are subscribed to and rendered in a webpage frontend.

From the frontend I first I make a call to tell the backend to start publishing the info. Then I subscribe to the topic.

**EDIT** The idea here is that I want to publish information from the backend to view on the frontend but there's no need for it to be published all the time. So when the page loads I want to send a message to tell it to start being published and then stop it when it's not needed anymore.

This is the relevant parts of the frontend code.

```
function connect() {
    var connection = new autobahn.Connection(
        {
            url: "ws://com.example.wamp:8765/ws",
            realm: "info"
        });

    connection.onopen = function (session) {
        // ...
        session.call("com.example.startPublish");
        // ...        
        session.subscribe("com.example.info", onInfo);
        // ...
    };

    connection.onclose = function (reason, details) {
        // ...
        session.unsubscribe("com.example.info");
        // ...
    };

    connection.open();
}

$(function() {
    connect();
});

function onInfo(args, kwargs) {
    $(".info").text(kwargs.info);
}
```

In the backend I do some processing to get the info and publish it. This is the backend code:

```
var publishInfoInterval = null;
var session;

var connection = new autobahn.Connection(
    {
        url: "ws://com.example.wamp:8765/ws",
        realm: "info"
    });

function getInfo() {
    // ...
    return duration;
}

function publishInfo() {
    publishInfoInterval = setInterval(function() {
        session.publish("com.example.info", [], {
            "info": getInfo(),
        });
    }, 10000);
}

function startPublish() {
    publishInfo();
}

function stopPublish() {
    clearIntervals();
}

function clearIntervals() {
    if(publishInfoInterval) {
        clearInterval(publishInfoInterval);
        publishInfoInterval = null;
    }
}

connection.onopen = function(sess) {
    session = sess;
    sess.register("com.example.startPublish", startPublish).then(
        function() {
            console.log("Registered startPublish");
        }
    );

    sess.register("com.example.stopPublish", stopPublish).then(
        function() {
            console.log("Registered stopPublish");
        }
    );
};

connection.onclose = function(reason, details) {
    clearIntervals();
};

connection.open();
```

The problem I'm having is that when I refresh the page, it creates a new subscription. But the original subscription is still publishing the same info. So after refreshing the page I'm double subscribed.

I'm wondering what's the best way to handle this.

Comment: can you share the backend code?

Comment: @Klanjabrik Backend code added

Comment: I thought this would be straight forward. But from the lack of responses I think maybe I just have a bad design that should be reworked.

Comment: Lets make it clear, the goal is all subscribers only get one message?